# Web application architecture design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, architecture

I'm building application which consists wordpress mu as  blogs engine and my rails app as core of application. And there is a moment when I have a big problem:

I think it might be really hard to do and I may not avoid doing some core changes, but first I want to ask here.

I have my ruby on rails application at domain.com - I want to use wordpress mu as blogs engine (this is part of website concept) using subdomains (user.domain.com user2.domain.com etc) but wordpress can't be at domain.com directly because there have to be my rails app. Is it possible to run wordpress in something like domain.com/wp but catch subdomains in *.domain.com (as I said, I'm aware that I may have to dig into the wordpress core) or is it completely impossible?

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer actually. 
I'm going to set up WordPress MU under wp.domain.com for example and register account in `wp.domain.com/user1` `wp.domain.com/user2` and rewrite it to `user1.domain.com` and `user2.domain.com` in haproxy.

I hope that could help anyone in future.